# View does not contain a definition for RemoveView error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm getting the error below when I rebuild my xamarin application using MyAdapter class.

The Code is: CS1061

I googled this but nothing that relates to my situation came up.

Here is the error message and also the code I'm using inside MyAdapter.js. Thanks!

[image: Error log]

```
public override void DestroyItem(View container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
        {
            container.RemoveView((View)@object);
        }
```

Comment: RemoveView is a method on ViewGroup, not View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jason. RemoveView is a method on ViewGroup, not View

So therefore, code is updated as follows.

```
public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
        {
            container.RemoveView((View)@object);
        }
```